# Pinterest board list

Tags: api, rss, pinterest

I am looking for a way to get the list of board names from a given username. I know pinterest already provides rss for all the pins from a given user and for all the pins from a given pinboard.

All Pins from a given user: pinterest.com/[user]/feed.rss

All pins from a given user and board: pinterest.com/[user]/[board-name]/rss

Now I need a way to get the list of boards from a given user, not the pins. I know there is a way to do it because -> pinreach.com does it.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

RSS feed only has 25 pins. To get boards or all the pins, you have to crawl the site. There is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another Unofficial API with Documentation for Pintrest
http://pinterestapi.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can check out this unofficial Pinterest API, you can search boards by username - https://www.mashape.com/ismaelc/pinterest-1#endpoint-Show-User-Boards

Sample result below:

```
    {
  "body": [
    {
      "name": "Books Worth Reading",
      "href": "http://pinterest.com/ismael/books-worth-reading/",
      "num_of_pins": 6,
      "cover_src": "http://media-cache-ec7.pinterest.com/222x/0c/31/22/0c3122735319edbf9b8aae28c9b22f86.jpg",
      "thumbs_src": [
        "http://media-cache-ec6.pinterest.com/75x75/2a/2d/7b/2a2d7b6f20f7518269b310b25d876810.jpg",
        "http://media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/75x75/e6/05/05/e6050519c5686ae27ad649500965f39c.jpg",
        "http://media-cache-ec5.pinterest.com/75x75/07/64/c3/0764c392bae2b073c4c862a6503f09d6.jpg",
        "http://media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/75x75/61/35/0a/61350ab6eb4bb0b0d09f7c191bf30d55.jpg"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "My Style",
      "href": "http://pinterest.com/ismael/my-style/",
      "num_of_pins": 0,
      "cover_src": false,
      "thumbs_src": false
    },
    {
      "name": "For the Home",
      "href": "http://pinterest.com/ismael/for-the-home/",
      "num_of_pins": 0,
      "cover_src": false,
      "thumbs_src": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Favorite Places & Spaces",
      "href": "http://pinterest.com/ismael/favorite-places-spaces/",
      "num_of_pins": 0,
      "cover_src": false,
      "thumbs_src": false
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "count": 4
  }
}
```

Comment: Sucks, that particular api is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now using the Official Pinterest API using the hook:
`https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/boards/?access_token=********&fields=id%2Cname%2Curl`

First, you will need to authenticate and get an acce3ss token. 
The getting started doc do a good job at explaining how. https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/